# Django, Haystack: show the time took by a search

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have a Django app that uses [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/). Is it possible to show after a search, in the search result page, how much time the search took ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `time` module from python to achieve that:

```
import time

start = time.time()
# code which performs search
end = time.time()
time_taken = end - start
```

Push `time_taken` to your template.

Comment: I did like this, but I was thinking that maybe there is something more specific made inside Haystack. Thanks for the answer anyway :)